# How to use snprintf like strncat?

Tags: c

```
char src1[4+1];
char src2[4+1];
char target[4+1];

strncpy(src1, "1234", sizeof(src1));
strncpy(src2, "ABCD", sizeof(src2));

snprintf(target, sizeof(target), "%3s%1s", src1, src2);
target[4] = '\0';

printf("result: %s\n", target);
```

Result is "1234" but I wanted to make "123A".

```
strncpy(src1, "1234", sizeof(src1));
strncpy(src2, "ABCD", sizeof(src2));

strncpy(target, src1, 3);
strncat(target+3, src2, 1);
printf("result: %s\n", target);
```

When I use strncat instead of snprintf, it works well.

Can someone explain why this code (snrpintf) works differently than I thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number is a minimum.

> In no case does a nonexistent or small field width cause truncation of a field; if the result of a conversion is wider than the field width, the field is expanded to contain the conversion result.

For `%s`, you can use the precision to specify a maximum

> [An optional precision] gives [...] the maximum number of characters to be printed from a string for `s` and `S` conversions.

So use

```
snprintf(target, sizeof(target), "%3.3s%1.1s", src1, src2);
```

(No need for the `target[4] = '\0';` with this!)